# How do you say, "How do you say ...?"

Tags: phrase-request

What are some good questions that I can use as a Korean leaner to help expand my Korean vocabulary?  In particular, how do I ask someone how to say an English word or phrase in Korean?

Examples (and my attempts at saying them in Korean):

- "How do you say 'XYZ'?" 어떻게 말해요 "XYZ"?  (I don't really know to handle quoted phrases in Korean, so I don't know if I did that correctly)
- "What is this?": 이것 뭐예요? (this phrase is really only helpful for learning about nouns that are physically in your presence)

Did I write those questions in Korean correctly?  Are there any other good questions I can ask people to help me learn Korean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of this answer, we will assume that your listener has some basic understanding of English.

Suppose I wanted to ask a Korean speaker (using Korean)

> "How do I say 'It is a pleasure to meet you' in Korean?"

I can then say

> 'It is a pleasure to meet you'는 한국말로 어떻게 말해요? (more formally 말합니까?)

The 한국말로 part indicates that you are asking them how to say the phrase *in Korean*.

A similar thing can be done with shorter phrases or nouns:

> 'Sunflower'는 한국말로 어떻게 말해요?

For a single word, we can also say

> 'Sunflower'는 한국말로 뭐라(고) 해요?

Suppose that a Korean speaker tells you that sunflower in Korean is 해바라기. You can then say

> 아, 예. 감사합니다. '해바라기' (attempt to say new word). 발음이 어때요? (Or 발음이 괜찮아요?)

This means "Oh, yes. Thank you. [attempt to say word]. How is my pronunciation?" This can verify your listening and your pronunciation skills while learning new words.

Answer (score 2):

> "How do you say 'XYZ'?"

‘XYZ’ 를 어떻게 부르나요?  Or ‘XYZ’를 어떻게 발음 하나요

> "What is this?"

이것은 무엇입니까?  or  이게 뭡니까?
           or  as situation  이게 무엇인지 알 수 있을까요?